# Activity cannot be applied

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I try to do one simple application, in that Intent Not working, it shows this error:

```
startActivities(android.content.Intent[]) in Activity cannot be Applied to (android.content.Intent)
```

---

```
public void btn_next1(View v){Intent intent2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Page2.class);
  startActivities(intent2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `startActivity(intent2);`

instead of `startActivities(intent2);`

`startActivities()` is used when you are launching multiple new activities.

Answer (score 1):

since you only have 1 Activity to start through an intent use `startActivity()` instead of `startActivities()`

```
Intent intent2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Page2.class);
startActivity(intent2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write startActivity(); instead of activities like this:

```
public void btn_next1(View v){Intent intent2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Page2.class);
startActivity(intent2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use startActivity Instead startActivities

```
  public void btn_next1(View v){
      Intent intent2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Page2.class);
      startActivity(intent2);
  }
```